# Tomcat's server status login problems

Tags: java, tomcat, status

I use VPS server with Debian8 and installed Tomcat8.0.45, Java8, MySQL. I use command line through PuTTY.

I started tomcat and in web browser I could see "If you're seeing this, you've successfully installed Tomcat. Congratulations!" which means everything is fine. Then I tried to check status of the server or in other words when I tried to access http://ip_adress:8080/manager then popud up prompt window and required login and password. 
I already uncommented user-roles in tomcat-users.xml file and added this:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager,tomcat,manager-gui,admin-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status"/>
```

Then I restarted tomcat server and typed login and password but still I am asked for login and password. Whatever I type in each time pops up loging window and I cannot access server status site.
Does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. Instead of use command: *systemctl stop tomcat* which seems to not stopping server, I used ***./shutdown.sh***.